# What does "further embodiment" mean?

Tags: meaning, legalese

I am reading a legal paper and I see this "further embodiment" a lot. I wonder what it means?

Thank you

Comment: Is it used with reference to a patent?

Comment: Yes it is in a patent paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a clear description of what the term 'embodiment' in legal terms and in your context mean: (further means 'additional')

[Embodiment](http://inventors.about.com/od/definations/g/embodiment.htm):

> by definition is a manner in which an invention can be made, used, practiced or expressed.
>   Embodiment in Patent Applications
>
> - The phrase embodiment will be in your patent application, as part of the "legalese" used. In a patent application the specification will include descriptions of the preferred embodiments. If you read a patent you will often see a section headlined DESCRIPTION OF THE PREFERRED EMBODIMENT. You will often refer to some aspect of your invention as an embodiment in descriptions.

Source: http://inventors.about.com/od/definations/g/embodiment.htm